# React Testing Library does not find elements using getAllByTestId after initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a very simple component where I am trying to simulate an API call to get some movies with a slight delay.

I want to write a test which tests that the movies are gathered and then rendered to screen.

I am trying to use `screen.getAllByTestId` to do this, however it always fails.  It is as if it doesn't re-render and therefore does not get the updated change.

I have added a testid onto the elements and can see these in the DOM.

Can anyone help as to why this isn't finding them after they appear?

[image]

Here is the full component code...

```js
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // simulate API call to get
    setTimeout(() => {
      const movies = [{ title: 'Titanic' }, { title: 'Back To The Future' }];
      setMovies(movies);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {movies.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {movies.map((x) => (
            <div data-testid='movies'>{x.title}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the full test code...

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const movieTiles = screen.getAllByTestId('movies');
  expect(movieTiles).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

Here is the error from the test

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [Fake Timers](https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers)  when your code uses timers (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `clearTimeout`, `clearInterval`).

Use `jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)` to move ahead in time by 1000ms.

Don't forget `act()` helper function:

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. react-dom/test-utils provides a helper called `act()` that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions:

Since we run the `setState` function that will change the component state 1000ms ahead of time, we must wrap this operation (`jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)`) in the `act()` function.

Otherwise, you will get warning:

> Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

E.g.

`App.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const movies = [{ title: 'Titanic' }, { title: 'Back To The Future' }];
      setMovies(movies);
    }, 1000 * 10);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {movies.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {movies.map((x, idx) => (
            <div key={idx} data-testid="movies">
              {x.title}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.test.jsx`:

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

describe('68460159', () => {
  test('renders learn react link', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<App />);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000 * 10);
    });
    const movieTiles = screen.getAllByTestId('movies');
    expect(movieTiles).toHaveLength(2);
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68460159/App.test.jsx (7.878 s)
  68460159
    ✓ renders learn react link (33 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.jsx  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.678 s, estimated 10 s
```

Comment: Brilliant, so will this be the same for if I do API calls? I was just using a timer above to simulate but I get the same issue when I use API call which has a slight delay

Comment: @user3284707 It's different for API calls, you need to set up a mock API server using msw and use `await waitFor()` to wait for the component state change.  See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro

Comment: Ahh ok thank you, so you can’t use a component which has a real API call inside is that right? I’m a bit confused at how I can use a real component which is using a real API call and substitute this for a mock one for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue without having `setTimeout`s in hooks or anything. What worked for me was transitioning from `getAllBy*` to `await findAllBy*` and making the whole test `async` of course. Everything else stayed the same and it suddenly passed ✅

Sharing just in case someone is loosing hours with the issue above as I was.